# Java byte to int auto convert

Tags: java

i want to ask if you know that following code will give cast exception.

```
byte b = 50;
b = b * 2;
```

Java convert byte to int before solving the equation. Then definition of b will give cast exception.

Comment: the answer is in your question *Java convert byte to int before solving the equation*

Comment: I know that i kind of answer to my own question. But IMHO this is not good, that byte that have +256 range will give ClassCastException. This should be programmer problem to cast numbers in a correct way, as it is in C++. Is there any option in Java to disable automatically casting to int when there is an equation to solve?

Comment: @MichałStankiewicz Java has a different design philosophy than C/C++. In many situations when C/C++ allows an operation as "probably right", Java will disallow it as "probably wrong". This makes the language more lenient to newcomers, because more errors are caught at compile time. For example, requiring a cast in a situation like the one you described above is a way to ask you to confirm your intentions, rather than assuming that you don't mind truncation. Throwing an exception would be a sub-par solution for performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for code to throw `ClassCastException` the code needs to compile. This code, on the other hand, will not compile as-is, because the second line will trigger an error:

> error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte

This is because multiplication produces an `int`.

If you replace the assignment with compound assignment, the error will go away:

```
b *= 2; // This compiles and runs correctly
```

Comment: Ok. Nice, quick solution. But i was thinking, byte, char, int, float etc. Are Java primitives. So as in C/C++. Can you override byte class so that b = b * 2; will give correct code? I know that you can do such things in C++ but i don't know if Java primitive types can be override with using override +,-, *, % methods?

Comment: @MichałStankiewicz No, Java does not support operator overrides even for user-defined types, let alone the primitive ones. If you would like to hide the cast, writing a method (say, `static byte mult(byte a, int k)`) can help hiding the cast inside the method.

Comment: Ok. Ty for your answer. In work i used OOP, and i never have wondered about simple casting ☺ one more time, Ty for help.